# ftp_ssl_connect not taking User and pass

Tags: php, ftp

I Have a function which talks to Ftp server from My apache webserver.

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

getting warning while compiling as below.

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Please login with USER and PASS.
```

The same function is running if I change the function call from `ftp_ssl_connect` to `ftp_connect`

I have openSSL enabled.